# Python subprocess.Popen, .run, or .call would not work on bootsect.exe

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I tried invoking bootsect.exe with subprocess.Popen, subprocess.run, subprocess.call, or even os.system but I keep getting the error below...

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 340, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

For instance, I get this error if use the code below...

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen('bootsect')
```

I can run diskpart or cmd using Popen but not bootsect for some reason. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your code works for me so I will ask the obvious: can you run bootsect on cmd successfully?

Comment: Yes I can run it from cmd. Maybe I need to upgrade my Windows.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón May I ask what version of Windows 10 you are on? I am currently on v1903.

Comment: Version 2004 (build 19041.450). I was thinking that it could be a problem with your `PATH` environment variable. When I run `where bootsect` con cmd I see `C:\Windows\System32\bootsect.exe`, which is in the same folder as `cmd.exe`, so it would not make sense that you could run one but not the other.

Comment: Hi @HernánAlarcón, I upgraded to Version 2004 (build 19041.450). I also got the following...
```C:\Users\username>where bootsect
C:\Windows\System32\bootsect.exe```
```C:\windows\system32``` and ```%SystemRoot%\system32``` are also in my System variables named Path.